# accessing file of another drive

Tags: php, iis-7

previously I could download wav file in php and IIS. But now file is not downloadable.I don't know what is going wrong . After installing and changeing php 5.3 to php 5.4 with php manager in IIS, the file is not able to downloaded. I have link to file to download it which looks like this:

```
       <a href="download.php?voice='$filename'"> Download </a>
```

download.php scripts

```
     <?php
       $filename = $_GET['voice'];
       $dir = 'd:/temp_file/voice/';
       if(is_file($dir.$filename))
        {
          header('Content-type: audio/wav');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$filename.'"');
          echo file_get_contents($dir.$filename);
       }
      ?>
```

while I was trying to find the mistake why file is not downloadable, I remove if statement and run program, it does prompt window download file with audio player of empty wav file. So, I conclude that there is mistake in path which is not allowing to access file of another drive. I have php code in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ but wav file to be download is in the d:\temp_file\voice path. What Should I have to do?

Comment: Obviously, the file `$dir.$filename` does not exists for the PHP file-system-implementation (`is_file($dir.$filename)` equals `FALSE`). Please specify the concrete filename in question (what does `var_dump($dir.$filename);` output?), ensure it exists on disk and is accessible by PHP (filesystem permissions).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe PHP [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction.

Try to add `d:/temp_file/voice/`, to its content in `php.ini`.

**Update**

I never used IIS, but another thing that you have to check is if the IIS User have permission to read that directory. Try to add, just for test, `Everyone` with all permission to `d:\temp_file\voice`.

Comment: how can I eliminate this restriction in IIS 7

Comment: Have you made same tests? Like adding that directive, or check file permission with `fileperms()`?

Comment: I have tested by placing file inside wwwroot folder and outside.... while file inside wwwroot is downloadable and outside one does not

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what is going wrong

Then [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php), for what it looks like to me it's a syntax error at           `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$filename.'"')`, you're missing a quote (`'`) after `filename='"`. But since you say it has worked (and works without the `if`), I'd say that's a copy paste error.

Then do a `var_dump($filename)`, which might contain quotes, since you put those around the URL in the link (`<a href="download.php?voice='$filename'">`). The file `D:/temp_file/voice/'foo.wav'` might not exist.